# EF DbContext in WCF Services

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I am creating an application that uses EF as its data access orm.

My entities are losing its state, causing that whenever I save a new entity, any objects in relationships are marked as new and try to be inserted as well.

How do I instance my DbContext once per WCF call so I use the same context in the whole service call and prevent it from bieng disposed and let my entities with an inconsistent state?

I used to store the context in the HttpContext when I did web apps, but in WCF there is no such thing as HttpContext.

Where can I store it so is used per call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpContext in WCF.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

I usually cache my DbContext in HttpContext using [structuremap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/)'s HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped:

```
For<IDbContext>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() => new MyDbContext());
```

This can be done manually using `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

I suppose it could be done differently in pure WCF but it's ok to use aspNetCompatibilityEnabled - imo.

Cheers!